# What is the way to hook all wordpress email

Tags: plugin-development, email, smtp

I have a wordpress site that have plugins: Contact form 7, WP Mail SMTP Plugin by Mail Bank, Spartpost...All of these plugins are able to send out email by anyway (wp_mail, smtp, http api)...

I am developing another plugin that will do my custom action on each sent out email by any plugin.

Currently, I can do the custom action on contact form 7 email with:

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'my_custom_action', 10, 1);
```

My question: is there any hook, filter or something that is general to wordpress email? Instead of use action/filter of every plugins?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every WordPress email usually uses `wp_mail()`. Which is actually a wrapper of [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). Find out this [`wp_mail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/) functions documentation and source code, you'll find some hooks there which will be useful to you cases.

> But keep it in mind that, those hooks will be applicable only if the mail is sent by using `wp_mail()`. If any email is send by any other function like the *PHP* native `mail()` function then the hooks may not work.

Comment: Hi @the_dramatist,

Thanks for your answer. Actually, I already add:
    
    add_filter('wp_mail','my_custom_action', 10,1);

But it no use. At least, I run test mail of SMTP Plugin by Mail Bank but my custom action not get executed.

Comment: As I said, if the plugin isn't using `wp_mail()` function then the hooks will not work. So, have look in to the plugin's source code and see what function of method they are using to send the e-mail. This way you'll get an overview on why it's not working.

Comment: Thank the_dramatis, the plugin actually use another way to send mail.